# Dynamically creating google app_engine ndb objects

Tags: django, google-app-engine

I am trying to use google's ndb model, adding some auto fields and definitions prior to model definition. The below code works well. My question is, though, any specific ndb model implementation is not used ( given I will be destroyed, if google changes anything) do you see any issue with portability of below

```
    class MetaModel(type):
        def __new__(cls,name,bases,attrs):
           super_new = super(MetaModel,cls).__new__
           if name == "Model":
               return super_new(cls,name,bases,attrs)
           if attrs.get('auto_date_time',True):
               attrs['date_add'] = ndb.DateTimeProperty(auto_now_add= True)
               attrs['date_upd'] = ndb.DateTimeProperty(auto_now= True)
           attrs['_get_kind'] = classmethod(get_kind)
           attrs['__name__'] = name

           attr_meta = attrs.get('Meta',None)
           if attr_meta is None:
              meta = type('meta',(object,),dict())
           else:
              meta = attr_meta

           kwargs= {}
           model_module = sys.modules[attrs['__module__']]
           kwargs['app_label'] = model_module.__name__.split('.')[-2]
           _meta = Options(meta,name,**kwargs)
           attrs['_meta'] = _meta

           return type(name,(ndb.Model,),attrs)

    class Model(object):
        __metaclass__ = MetaModel

    class TesTModel(Model):
        name = ndb.StringProperty(indexed=False)

    tm = TestModel(name='This is the test model')
    tm.put()
```

Comment: What is your aim in doing this? Why not create a normal base class with the relevant field?

Comment: Hi Daniel, first of all Happy New Year !!! I do not want to create base class as I want to assign attributes to ndb object on the fly. for e.g in above if only auto_date_time is set to true in TestModel date_add and date_upd will be added to ndb _properties else not. This can be done by defining different base classes but its against DRY

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems pretty fragile.  Sounds like an [expando model](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/entities#expando) might work for you?

**Edit** (*based on clarification below*):  metaclasses and type really should be a last resort.  They're confusing and hard to get right.  For example, in your code snippet, subclasses of Model get ndb's metaclass instead of the one above:

```
class T1(Model):
  pass

>>> T1().to_dict()
T1 {'date_upd': None, 'date_add': None}


class T2(Model):
  auto_date_time = False

class T3(T2):
  auto_date_time = True

>>> T2.__metaclass__
<class 'ndb.model.MetaModel'>
>>> T3().to_dict()
{}
```

You can avoid some craziness by deriving your metaclass from ndb.MetaModel:

```
class MyMetaModel(ndb.MetaModel):
    def __new__(cls, name, bases, attrs):
       return super(MyMetaModel,cls).__new__(cls, name, bases, attrs)

class MyModel(ndb.Model):
    __metaclass__ = MyMetaModel

class AutoTimeModel(MyModel):
   date_add = ndb.DateTimeProperty(auto_now_add=True)
   date_upd = ndb.DateTimeProperty(auto_now=True)
```

Comment: Honestly I first thought of ndb Expando as an option, but for that I need to instantiate the class before adding fields. Also I need sometime in my case, to add some static _meta information in the model class which I can access without instantiating the class. Do you think its possible with Expando?

Comment: Yes, building an object with ndb's metaclass was intentional. As you may observe I never returned an object created by super but a new type with ndb.Model as base which is equivalent of writing  `class Test(ndb.Model)` but just with some added attributes which can be accessed as `Test.attribute` rather than `Test().attribute`. Have already tried above methods using base classes, but using metaclasses gives more flexibility as yes was opted for as a last resort :( . Again would like to ask what could possibly break this down.

Comment: I do not see anything particularly fragile in terms of compatibility.